# Eighth Slash Notes for a Simile

Tags: notation, repeats

I know that if you want to make a SIMILE part, you can put (as my picture) quarter notes, then convert (in Sibelius) to SLASH NOTATION and enter the text that says SIMILE.

Here is the picture:
[image: example of slash notation]

The point is that in the picture above when you have 4 quarter notes in the previous bar, you can convert to slash notation simply like that, but what happens if in the previous bar you have eighth or sixteenth notes? How do you interpret slashes for a SIMILE with eighth or sixteenth notes?

For example, if 4 slashes represent 4 quarter notes, then should 8 eighth notes be 8 slashes, and 16 sixteenth notes be 16 slashes?

Comment: Why are there dots on top of the slashes in your picture?

Comment: It was just a test and the dot is staccato. I just copied the notes on another voice, then make the quarter notes and then hide voice 1 and leave the slashes on. But I wanted to be sure if the 4 slashes are good to represent eighth notes SIMILE also.

Comment: if you want to indicate a certain rhythm I would think about switching to slash notation with stems to give a clue to the rhythm you want the player to perform. If it´s only about making clear that there will be another bar counting four beats, the four slash notation is pretty okay.

Comment: Ok perfect then photo is ok because is just to repeat. In case of other case use stop time or rhythmic notation. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is usually no need for slashed eighth (or sixteenth notes), quarter note slashes work just as well and make the page less cluttered. For example:
[image]
For specific rhythmic figures you can use slashed eights/sixteenths.

If you need a figure repeated exactly, then you should use one bar repeat signs instead of slashes.